# Can i Include a navigation controller inside my project.?

Tags: iphone, navigation, controller

I am currently doing an iphone application in which i need to include a navigation controller in my 3rd view. there are tutorials for navigation controller but its in the first view itself. When i include it in the third view the view is not loading. can anyone help me please...
Shibin

Comment: I seem to recall having seen apps that start out without navigation controllers and then switch to them.  You might want to show us some code snippets to see how you are doing it.

Comment: just need to add a navigation controller in to the second view of a new project which is a view based application. can you help me.?

Answer (score 1):

When you add the second ViewController, then do:

```
[secondViewController.view addSubview:[navigationController view]];
```

Or you can add it to your rootViewController.  It really depends on what you are trying to do.  That's why I was asking for some code.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I think i need the second one.. that is the rootviewcontroller thing. i will try to send you the code.. can you give me you email id. so that i can contact you. shibin.moideen@mediaus.com

Comment: Hi, mahboudz.. if you please send me your email id, i will send you the whole project. please do help me. i am very much new to this domain... please do help me.